# smbldap-tools: how do I list groups

Tags: debian, unix, ldap, openldap

I'm using smldap-tools to administrate a small office network. Whenever I add a new user I always forget which groups I've created and therefore which groups I need to add a user to. Is there an easy way to simply list groups?

Many thanks,

(I really need an smbldap-tools tag, but none current exists and my rep isn't high enough to create it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use getent to see what groups your workstation knows of:

```
getent group
```

will give you all the groups from the administrative databases specified in /etc/nsswitch.conf; you will get both local as ldap groups. Otherwise you might want to script it yourself, you use the smbldap-tools, so you have Perl and Net::LDAP installed ;-)